# How to specify full filename instead of short filename as an argument of ifstream or ofstream

Tags: c++, file-io

I am writing a program to deal with optimal public transport routes. Therefore, I have some files loaded in folders.
I might need to read them. For example, I have a file with path timetables_0006\weekday.txt. I would like to read it and use the data in the file. However, I have only encountered ifstream with short filename, like

```
ifstream input ("weekday.txt")
```

I tried

```
ifstream input ("timetables\_0006\weekday.txt")
```

and failed.
Is it possible to put full filename, or are there any other alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: The backslash `\\` also has a special meaning in string literals, which you seem to be oblivious of.

Comment: Try `ifstream input (R"aw(timetables\_0006\weekday.txt)aw")` or `ifstream input ("timetables\\_0006\\weekday.txt")` or the simplest of all, use forward slashes: `ifstream input ("timetables/_0006/weekday.txt") `. Another variant: `ifstream input (std::filesystem::path("timetables") / "_0006" / "weekday.txt") `

Comment: `"timetables\_0006\weekday.txt"` -- Did your compiler warn you about this string literal and that there are unknown escape sequences being used?

Comment: Backslash needs to be escaped by another backslash. Or for plain and short filenames, use forward slash (it has been supported since the DOS days).

Comment: Use / instead of \

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` starts an [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), just like in `\n`, which is why it doesn't work.

> are there any other alternatives?

Yes

- Using raw string literals:

  ```cpp
  R"aw(timetables\_0006\weekday.txt)aw"
  ```
- By escaping the backslashes, `\\`:

  ```cpp
  "timetables\\_0006\\weekday.txt"
  ```
- By using forward slashes instead:

  ```cpp
  "timetables/_0006/weekday.txt"
  ```
- By building a [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path):

  ```cpp
  std::filesystem::path("timetables") / "_0006" / "weekday.txt"
  ```